# TFS solution is downloaded along with the Nuget Packages but the references are missing?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget

I'm training 5 people on using Visual Studio. They've mapped their drives and have "downloaded" the solution from TFS which contains 10 projects. All located at the same depth in TFS folder structure. When the new folks download the solution there's one project that doesn't get the NUGET references even though the Package folder (created by NUGET) is at the same depth of the other 10 projects when viewed in TFS.

We know how to add these manually but is there a way to automatically have VS do it?  Why would only one project lose it's reference with the Package Folder right there?

Comment: Negative vote with no reason is unproductive and reflects poorly on the lazy person who cast the vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Fix:

Unload all projects first, then right click and select edit project.

Find this line:

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\nuget.targets" />
```

Comment it out.
Reload all the projects and compile.

This applies to Nuget api version 2.
Note you may configure all projects for Nuget at the solution level.

[image: Configuration at the solution level]

The package manager for the solution presents a set of check boxes for every project along with the buttons (Install or Uninstall).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are still using MSBuild-Integrated package restore approach. If NuGet recognizes that the MSBuild-Integrated package restore approach is enabled for the solution, Automatic Package Restore is skipped.

You need to [migrating MSBuild-Integrated solutions to use Automatic Package Restore](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore), then the packages will be restored automatically.

In addition, you need to update you NuGet manager to the latest version in VS **Tools--Extensions and Updates**. And make sure Visual Studio is configured to '*Allow NuGet to download missing packages*' and '*Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio*' in VS **Tools--Options--NuGet Package Mnager--General**.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent help.  The problem was that only 2 of the 10 projects were using the old method.  I unloaded each project and edited the project file looking for references to Nuget I removed the ones indicated in the link above.  Next, at the solution layer in the .nuget folder I left only the Nuget.Config file which tells TFS don't include the nuget content when checking the code in.  I checked the project in, created a new workspace,code was downloaded and compile worked!

Comment: P.S. The reason that only one project wouldn't restore properly is that it was one of the two that still had the old method.  If you have recently upgraded NUGET you may run into this same issue.